# How to get content from FileStreamResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using a third party library in which one of the methods returns `FileStreamResult`.

```
public FileStreamResult GenerateFile(OutFormat format, dynamic params);
```

An action in my controller calls this method:

```
public ActionResult GenerateExcel()
{
    Utils.XCore core = new Utils.XCore(...); // where ... are contructor params
    // ... other codes here ...
    return core.GenerateFile(OutFormat.EXCEL, new { FileName = "Report" });
}
```

This is going to be fine but sometimes I want to *merge multiple Excel worksheets into one* which is something like this:

```
public ActionResult GenerateExcel()
{
    Utils.XCore core = new Utils.XCore(...); // where ... are contructor params
    // ... other codes here ...
    var excel1 = core.GenerateFile(OutFormat.EXCEL, new { FileName = "rpt1" });
    var excel2 = core.GenerateFile(OutFormat.EXCEL, new { FileName = "rpt2" });
    var excel3 = core.GenerateFile(OutFormat.EXCEL, new { FileName = "rpt3" });

    var finalContent = combineFile(excel1, excel2, excel3);

    return new FileStreamResult(finalContent, "application/ms-excel")
       {
           FileDownloadName = "Report.xls"
       };
}
```

My problem now is I don't know how to get the content from `FileStreamResult`. Any ideas on how to do it? Even comments containing weblinks are pretty much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You need to reset the seek origin of the stream before using it to save/prompt user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121703/asp-net-mvc-filestreamresult-not-working-as-intended

Comment: @Papa i don't have any memorystream object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, you want to process/get the content from `FileStreamResult`. The class contains a property called `FileStream` which is a `Stream` object. Now, the stream object can now be saved as a file using the following modified code [from this site](http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4669/save-a-stream-to-a-file/):

```
private void streamToFile(Stream fileStream, string filePath)
{
    using (FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(filePath, 
                                    FileMode.Create, 
                                    FileAccess.Write))
    {
        int length = 1024;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[length];
        int bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        fileStream.Close();
        writeStream.Close();
    }
}
```

and the following is how to use:

```
var excel1 = core.GenerateFile(OutFormat.EXCEL, new { FileName = "rpt1" });
string filePath = "C:\\yourFileName.xls"; // path of your newly saved file 
using (Stream reportStream = excel1.FileStream)
{
     streamToFile(reportStream, filePath);
}
```